# Q: Python Django Docker - Unknown server host 'db' error when trying to make a super user

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use the command `python manage.py createsuperuser` and `docker exec -it veganetwork-db-1 python manage.py createsuperuser` to add myself as a superuser to my microservices project, however when I try to run both of these commands I get `Unknown server host 'db'` in my Windows Powershell, here is the entire error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'veganetwork.auth_user' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 100, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 140, in get_default_username
    auth_app.User._default_manager.get(username=default_username)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 425, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'veganetwork.auth_user' doesn't exist")
PS C:\Users\trevo\OneDrive\Desktop\veganetwork\veganetworkmain> python manage.py migrate auth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown server host 'db' (11001)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trevo\OneDrive\Desktop\veganetwork\veganetworkmain\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\trevo\OneDrive\Desktop\veganetwork\veganetworkmain\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\database.py", line 13, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    if not (self.connection.sql_mode & {'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'}):
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 405, in sql_mode
    sql_mode = self.mysql_server_data['sql_mode']
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 366, in mysql_server_data
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown server host 'db' (11001)")
```

I have tried some other methods in some other posts like creating a class named Command in my manage.py script to create the superuser: [Create django super user in a docker container without inputting password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027203/create-django-super-user-in-a-docker-container-without-inputting-password), using `docker-compose run django python manage.py createsuperuser` rather than the regular docker command which is `docker exec -it veganetwork-db-1 python manage.py createsuperuser`: https://github.com/vchaptsev/cookiecutter-django-vue/issues/25, and finally trying to change the `depends_on` variable inside my docker-compose.yml file and restarting the docker container itself: [django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-2)")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024759/django-db-utils-operationalerror-2005-unknown-mysql-server-host-db-2/52025078). I have tried all of these solutions but they have all failed.

here is my docker-compose file as well as my dockerfile:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: veganetworkmain
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here, thank you!

Comment: I'm seeing two different errors here - one is `Table 'veganetwork.auth_user' doesn't exist`, and the other is `Unknown server host 'db'`. Are these caused by the same command, or different commands? If they're caused by different commands, can you include the command which caused the first error?

Comment: Second question - this kind of error is commonly caused by not running migrations. Have you run migrations?

Comment: Unknown server host Db is the command error I am experiencing now. I will also try to run some migrations as well. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure to run migrations from inside the `backend` container, or you'll get the same `Unknown server host` error.

Comment: Alright so I have tried to run the migrations through the backend container using this command: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run backend python manage.py makemigrations` but it says that no changes are detected

Comment: Are the migrations applied? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#the-commands